# Creating custom groups in Lync 2013 using Powershell with the SDK

Tags: powershell, sdk, lync

I'm trying to write some Powershell code that can create custom groups for Lync users. I'm writing the script using the Lync 2013 Model SDK, and so far I'm able to create a group successfully.

However, I need to have the group object returned after it's been created. According to this article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937292(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj937292%28v=office.15%29.aspx) groups are returned as an event argument after creation.

I've managed to subscribe to the correct event, and it triggers when I create a custom group, but the event arguments is empty and I can't seem to get the object of the newly created group.

This is my code so far. Am I subscribing to the event incorrectly?

```
#Importing SDK Dll
[string]$LyncModelDll = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Lync.Model.DLL"
Import-Module -Name $LyncModelDll

#Get Lync Client State
$objLyncClient = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()
Write-Host "Lync Client State:" $objLyncClient.State

# Lync Client Object
$cl = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()

Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $cl.contactmanager -EventName GroupAdded -action {CM_GroupAdded $sender $eventargs}

$addgroup = $cl.ContactManager.BeginAddGroup('Custom Group Name', $null, $null)

$cl.contactmanager.endaddgroup($addgroup)
```

Comment: What does `CM_GroupAdded` do? Where is it defined? When I put `Write-Host $eventargs.Group.Id` as the action for the event, it reported the ID of the newly created group just fine.

Comment: The CM_GroupAdded basically just writes out the contents of the parameters with Get-member. I just tried getting the ID and it worked. I'm still not getting any other properties though.

Comment: I was able to output [other properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.group.group_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt_members%28v=office.15%29.aspx) like `Name`, `Count` or `Type` in the same way. If something doesn't work for you I suspect the problem is with what you do in `CM_GroupAdded`.